# Nodejs : get stdout at once, not in chunks in childprocess.spawnSync

Tags: node.js

I am using nodejs "child_process.spawnSync" to perform some task.I receive the output data as chunks and not at once.I am using the following code i have a workaround.But is there any better way of doing this.

```
var cp = require('child_process');
var child = cp.spawnSync("g++", ['sample.cpp']); //the array is the arguments
var child1 = cp.spawn("./a.out")
var val = "Hello \n 1 2 3 4 5"
child1.stdin.write(val); //my command takes a markdown string...
var final="";
child1.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log('stdout: ' + data);
    final+=data
});

child1.on('exit',function(a,b){
    console.log(final);
});

child1.stdin.end();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct, this is the typical "generic" way to read the stdout from an async process.

In your case, to simplify, you could make use of the `input` option of spawnSync, and then read the resulting `stdout` buffer:

```
cp.spawnSync("g++", ['sample.cpp']);

var val = "Hello \n 1 2 3 4 5";
var result = cp.spawnSync('./a.out', { input: val });

console.log(result.stdout.toString());
```

Comment: This outputs "[object object]"

Comment: Interesting, what is `result.stdout`?

Comment: It should be a Buffer, which you turn into a string using `toString()`.

Comment: i tried running on a simple command..and it works , but outputs "[object object]" on my task.

Comment: I wonder if your task is failing (exiting with exit code >= 1)?  You should also check the `result.status` and `result.stderr` in this case.